# Conduction band energy level under illumination

Tags: visible-light, photons, semiconductor-physics

I am new to the field and my apologies if its trivial question.

Consider a semiconductor having valence and conduction band at certain energy level. When it is illuminated with photons having sufficient energy to excite electrons to conduction band, does the energy level of conduction band change? or it will have a fixed energy level position regardless of whether the semiconductor is under illumination or not?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE!

Comment: Electrons will be injected into the conduction band, but that does not mean the conduction band moves.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you. Can you please explain why the conduction band does not move, as after irradiation it is occupied with electrons having energy.

Comment: Because the conduction band electron states were perfectly fine electronic states of the material before occupation, and remain so after occupation.

Answer (score 0):

The band structure of a material is determined by the type and arrangement of the atoms in the material. Simply illuminating a material will not change the type of atoms or their arrangement, therefore it will not change the band structure. (Unless you're doing something really extreme like significantly heating the material, which could have some small effect on the spacing of the atoms and thus the band structure.)

Comment: @Inmaurer Thank you for this. I do have a follow up question. If this is a case then, people describe band bending at the interface when p and n-type semiconductor (or semiconductor and metal) come in contact. This band bending is physical or just theoretical?

Comment: The band bending is real. It's an extreme situation: you have a really high electric field (often on the order of 10s of kV/cm) such that, effectively, the band structure can be shifted at different points in space. Band bending only happens in heterostructures or non-uniformly doped semiconductors. It doesn't occur naturally in a semiconductor.